# Does Tony Stark have a separate Arc Reactor for his heart?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

Does Tony Stark have another Arc Reactor embedded in his body? Other than the Arc Reactors in the Iron Man suits, I mean.

Comment: Have you seen Iron Man 3? I don't want to spoil it for you, but if you're seeing anything past then, you're going to get differing answers.

Comment: @Axelrod - Hence why I've listed the films in which he does, and the film in which he doesn't. Simples.

Comment: @Richard Yes, you did a great job updating your answer to include something I asked about before I was going to post. -_-

Comment: @Axelrod - My heart bleeds for you :-P

Comment: Going by the movies, I thought the reactor embedded in his chest did double duty - keeping him alive AND powering his suit. Didn't think the suit had its own reactor.

Comment: Obviously , it says so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throughout the Iron Man films (I, II and III) Tony Stark has [arc reactors](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_Reactor) embedded in his chest. In the films they power the electromagnet that prevents shrapnel from entering his heart.

[image]

At the end of Iron Man III, he finally has the surgery needed to [remove the shrapnel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11424/how-did-tony-fix-himself-by-the-end-of-iron-man-3), obviating the need to have an arc reactor embedded into his chest.

Note that the latest MCU movies (Avengers II, Captain America: Civil War) are set *after* Iron Man III, which means that he ***doesn't*** have an arc reactor in his chest in these films.

Comment: You're killing me, Richard.

Comment: In fact, there are a couple of places in Civil War where you can see Tony's chest, and a scar is visible where the arc reactor once was.

Comment: Does this mean Loki could have been able to control Iron Man if he had the patience to wait until now before attacking? http://www.geeksandcleats.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/iron-man-loki-fiction.png

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Yes. It does.

Comment: How can Loki? His staff (mind stone) is now in vision

Comment: @Naib - It's only in The Vision because Iron Man helped take it off him. If he'd turned up a few years later, he'd have been able to control Tony.

Comment: Yup. There is a small window between IronMan3 and Avengers2 where this would be viable. What is the canon timeline

Comment: Oh, well that answers my question about Tony not dying in Civil War.

Comment: As depicted in the first *Iron Man* movie, the hole in his chest that the reactor fits into is rather large. Whatever did they fill it with? Also, it's quite possible that if Loki had waited, and the events of the first *Avengers* film didn't happen, Tony would not have gone through with the surgery.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Generally you'd fill such a large surgical cavity with a silicone implant or sterile collagen fleece.

Comment: @Richard - Normally I'd agree, but it seems like they'd have to replace a chunk of his sternum. Maybe in the MCU they can grow bone in a lab? I'd ask a new question, but it's rather apparent they don't go into details in the film.

Comment: i'm going to have to watch that again Irishpanda because i was specifically looking for a scar when i was watching civil war and failed to see one.

Comment: @JohnSensebe this is Tony Stark we're talking about. He could buy or invent something to fill up the space with.